# find the youngest student from date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below table:

```
name      id     DOB                        marks
rk         2     2006-02-03 00:00:00.000    30
mk         3     2006-07-07 00:00:00.000    30
pk         4     2006-04-09 00:00:00.000    30
sk         5     2006-05-03 00:00:00.000    30
fk         6     2006-08-09 00:00:00.000    30
nk         7     2007-08-06 00:00:00.000    30
```

How can I find the youngest student?

Comment: What database.?

Comment: It matters whether you're using Sql Server, Access, MySql, Oracle, etc, because all of those have slightly different syntax for limiting rows: `TOP` vs `LIMIT` vs `OFFSET/FETCH`.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Post your table as text (as you did) not as an image, and format it properly

Comment: Don't post images for sample data. It forces us to need to retype the data if we want to setup a test or use sqlfiddle.

Comment: Have you even tried anything?  If you have, where is it?

Comment: @Randhirkawade - The answer you accepted will show the oldest student, but you wanted the youngest, isn't it? You can try my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need the latest date of birth (assuming DOB is date of birth):

```
select max(dob) from yourtable
```

Then your query would be:

```
select name as youngestStudent, dob as dateOfBirth
from yourtable
where dob = (select max(dob) from yourtable)
```

Comment: He wants the student, not just their dob.

Comment: you are right :) the query i posted is to find the youngest by dob, it can easily be used then as a condition for selecting the name.

Comment: This query will show the oldest student, not youngest ! Isn't it ?

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir Yeah, could be. It has been asked in April :) Anyway, for it to match with the question I will just update it.

Answer (score 5):

You can order your table by descending date of birth and then filter the first result only, which in SQL Server can be done with

```
select  top 1 *
from    yourTable
order by DOB desc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. According to your given data "nk" is the youngest student, so you can use the following query :

```
    select * from yourtable
    where dob = (select max(dob) from yourtable)
```